# Filter a table with text and button inputs using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, filter, html-table

Is it possible to filter the same table with more than one input? If so- can it be done with both text and button based inputs?

Is it possible to add filtering buttons to this for example? (my apologies if it breaks. I tried trimming back the code as much as possible..):

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Albion Next Generation Arming Swords</title>

    </head>

        <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <header>

    <nav style="z-index: 999; float: right; width: 100%;>

    <div style="width: 25%; float: right; margin-top: 1%; margin-right: 1%; 
    font-family: Centaur; font-size: 16px" data-tip="Exe. 'Laird', 'Type 
    XII' or 'Scottish'">

    <input style="margin-left: 0%; width: 100%; " type="text" id="myInput" 
    onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder=" Filter by name or bladetype or key-
    term" title="Type in a name"></div>



    </nav>

    </header>
    <body>
    <section style="padding-top: 11%; float: left; width: 90%; z-index: 
    999999999999999">
    <table id="SwordTable" style="z-index: 999999999999999999999999; width: 
    100%; height: 100%; margin-right: 15%; padding-left: 2%; font-size: 80%" 
    cellpadding="2">
    <tbody>



    <tr>
    <td style="width: 100%">
    <td style="width: auto"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 5%">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="Albion Front Page.html">
    <img style="float: right" src="images/NORMAN.png" width="95%" 
    height="auto" alt=""/></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="desc">
    <p style="text-align: left; font-family: Centaur; font-size: 100%">The 
    Norman<br>Type Xa<br>$880</p>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 5%">
    <div style="width: 100%" class="dropdown">
    <a href="Albion Front Page.html">
    <img style="float: right" src="images/SENLAC.png" width="100%" 
    height="auto" alt=""/></a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="desc">
    <p style="text-align: left; font-family: Centaur; font-size: 100%">The 
    Senlac<br>Type Xa<br>$880</p>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
   <td style="padding-bottom: 5%">
   <div style="width: 100%" class="dropdown">
   <a href="Albion Front Page.html">
   <img style="float: right" src="images/Templar.png" width="98%" 
   height="auto" alt=""/></a>
   <div style="float: right" class="dropdown-content">
   <div class="desc">
   <p style="text-align: left; font-family: Centaur; font-size: 100%">The 
   Templar<br>Type Xa<br>$880</p>
   </div> 
   </div>
   </div>
   </td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 5%"><div class="dropdown"><a href="Albion 
    Front Page.html"><img style="float: right" src="images/REEVE.png" 
    width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/></a><div class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="desc"><p style="text-align: left; font-family: Centaur; 
    font-size: 100%">The Reeve<br>Late Anglo-Saxon sword<br>Type 
    X<br>$840</p></div> </div>
    </div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 5%"><div class="dropdown"><a href="Albion 
    Front Page.html"><img style="float: right" src="images/BAYEUX.png" 
    width="93%" height="auto" alt=""/></a><div class="dropdown-content"><div 
    class="desc"><p style="text-align: left; font-family: Centaur; font-
    size: 100%">The Bayeux<br>Type X<br>$880</p></div> </div>
    </div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 5%"><div class="dropdown"><a href="Albion 
    Front Page.html"><img style="float: right" src="images/VIGIL.png" 
    width="93%" height="auto" alt=""/></a><div class="dropdown-content"><div 
    class="desc"><p style="text-align: left; font-family: Centaur; font-
    size: 100%">The Vigil<br>Type X<br>$1,210</p></div> </div>
    </div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 5%"><div class="dropdown"><a href="Albion 
    Front Page.html"><img style="float: right" src="images/Oakshott.png" 
  width="98%" height="auto" alt=""/></a><div class="dropdown-content"><div 
  class="desc"><p style="text-align: left; font-family: Centaur; font-size: 
  100%">The Oakeshott<br>Type Xa<br>$1,210</p></div> </div>
    </div></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("SwordTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
     }        
   }
 }
 </script>
 </section>


 <div class="push" style="padding-bottom: 20%"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Basically, I want to add a number of search buttons beneath the search-bar that will filter products based on various traits.

Comment: too much code, add relevant blocks

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: It is hard to isolate relevant markup and JavaScript. Could you post the relevant markup and any relevant Javascript only. Also try to make a working snippet for a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Okay... Trimmed it back to the table that I want to filter and the java-script function that handles the type input..

Comment: Might want to look into [jQuery Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/).  Provides easy sorting, searching, filtering functionality via jQuery.

Comment: I will definitely look into jQuery Databases, however- is it possible at present to add buttons that when clicked, will add filterable text to the search bar?

Exe. user clicks "product category 1", "product category 1" appears in search bar, page shows only products of that category?

Ideally, I'd want the user to be able to click on a catagory, then use the search input to further filter said category.